# Does anyone has Win SNMP API C++ code example

Tags: winsnmp

SnmpSendMsg function usage to send SNMP Trap on Windows.
Does Win SNMP API support IPv6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the SNMP version, AFAIK SNMP version 3 has support for IPV6 and is backward compatible with IPV4. You need to check the SNMP devices and their versions.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.